# How can I build a referral system in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy

I have a website with a referal system, and I want the users to be able to see what users they referred, using a treeview.

My database table is set up so that when a user refers somebody with his referal code,
the new users gets an ID, a sponsor code (the referal code from his "sponser" aka the person who got him into this site) and a referal code (his own referal code to get other people to join under him).

I have no idea how i can get this info out of my MySQL database, and into a treeview script.

I would need to be able to let the user see all the people that he referred, 10 levels deep.

Is this possible and how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at hierarchical data (http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)

```
<?php

    function tree_view($index)
    {
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE SCode=$index");
        if (!mysql_num_rows($q))
            return;
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            echo '<li>';
            echo $arr['UserID']; //you can add another output there 
            tree_view($arr['RCode']);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('test') or die('Could not select database');

    tree_view(11111);
```

Comment: I prefer the nested set behavior in Doctrine ORM for this kind of relation

Comment: what does the $index stand for? and the tree_view(11111) what does that do?

Comment: $index is the SCode of the user that is passed to the query to get all    users sponsored by $index and Tree_view is the function that generate the representation of the sponsor tree

Comment: so the 11111 in tree_view(11111) should do the script with SCode 11111

Comment: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\productie\test.php on line 39

  if(!mysql_num_rows($q))  is the line that has the error.

Comment: yes, the 11111 should be the SCode of your user and you have to pass it as a variable to the function that print the tree. If your SCode is alphanumerical you have to surround it by '' in the query: "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE SCode = '$index' "