# need help with treeview from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, hierarchical-data

i want to build a treeview from a database.

the treeview should start with the user logged in (stored in the session as $UserID)

from there it should be able to view all his referrals (saved in the DB)

in the following image, you'll get an overview of the DB and how i want the treeview to look like.
[image]

how can i code this so i can integrate this into my website?
i've read up on treeview etc, but i can't seem to find a good solution for it.

also i want to limit this to 10 levels deep. how would i go about that?

if anybody would be kind enough to get me started with some code, i'd love that.

also i want the treeview to load node by node, instead of the whole treeview at once, seeing how it might get really big, and performance wise i still want it to be fast.

ps: bigger image at: http://imageshack.us/f/824/treeg.png/

Thanks :)

Comment: Heirachical data of almost any depth can be fast if you use the right data structure; see http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database for a MySQL approach.

Comment: hi, i've read that, but i have no idea on how to start implementing this.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149060/how-can-i-build-a-referral-system-in-php/7149099#7149099 where I've answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpulldown/.
It builds up a tree structure from a db to create a multi-level ajax selector.